# JQuery selector check the number of checkboxes has been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to is run some code if the number of `input[type="checkbox"]` is checked equal to the value of 2 or 3.

Here is an example of my JQuery:

```
if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 2 or 3) {
  // run some code
}
```

Im not sure how to program it to understand whether the value is 2 or 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$('#id').length` will **always** be 1. If you've duplicate IDs(_which you should not have_) `if $('[id="id"]').length === 2 || $('[id="id"]').length === 3) {`

Comment: @Tushar Im actually using it to figure out how many checkboxes has been checked so Im not using duplicate ID's. The code above is just an example of what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: Then use `$('.checkboxClass:checked').length`.

Comment: @Tushar -- sorry. misread.. :-)

Comment: I've used :checked. What im trying to is get it to figure out whether 2 or 3 have been checked hence why im using `length`

Comment: @Priark Change the selector from my first comment to the one in my second comment. So, it becomes `var checkedLen = $('checkboxSelector:checked').length; if (checkedLen === 2 || checkedLen === 3) {`

Comment: @Tushar That's got it working thank you. I'll put you as accepted answer if you answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the or operator `||`

```
if ($('#id').length === 2 || $('#id').length === 3) {
  // run some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on [Javascript logical operators](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp).  This is basic stuff.

Logical operators are used to determine the logic between variables or values.

Given that x = 6 and y = 3, the table below explains the logical operators:

```
Operator      Description      Example  
========================================================
&&            and              (x < 10 && y > 1) is true    
||            or               (x === 5 || y === 5) is false    
!             not              !(x === y) is true
```